# Micronaut ignores content-type that a client accepts

Tags: java, micronaut

I am trying to create a micronaut endpoint that produces JSON or XML responses dependently what client accepts. I have written some code

```
  @Get(value = "/notifications/{notificationId}", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  Notification fetchNotification(@PathVariable String notificationId);
```

In impelemation of this code I just make select into database and return POJO.
I assumed that if request header contains "accept - application/xml", micronaut should return a  response as XML. Also, for JSON. But I get a response as JSON independently on request header.
I made some investigation and found out that

```
io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler#prepareRouteForExecution
```

here micronaut creates a HttpResponse without contentType. After that, it picks first content-type in **produces** and returns the response as it. I have MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON on the first place, so micronaut returns JSON. If I change their order, micronaut returns XML.

Also, I have checked another endpoint, that should return just json

```
  @Get(value = "/notifications/last", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  Notification fetchLastNotification();
```

And I saw the same behaviour.
Why does micronaut ignore content-type that a client accepts? Should I create proper HttpResponse in a controller manually?

Comment: Are you using `io.micronaut.xml:micronaut-jackson-xml`?

Comment: yep, I am. Without it, I wouldn't serialize XML at all

Comment: "Without it, I wouldn't serialize XML at all" - That isn't true.  You can configure your own serializers.

Comment: Are you using Micronaut 2.0.x?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thak you. I was using 1.3.4. I updated Micronaut and not it works fine